# Multiple queries with limitation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get two types of items in one query. Is it possible to do it?

Items should be 3 * 2 items. it means all items are six. 3 items in `isFamous:true` and 3 items in `isBest:true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html):

```json
POST /_msearch
{"index": "your-index-name"}
{"size": 3, "query": { "term": { "isFamous": { "value": "true" } } } }
{"index": "your-index-name"}
{"size": 3, "query": {"term": { "isBest": { "value": "true" } } } }
```

This will issue two queries and bring their results in a single response. Another way would be using aggregations.

Comment: is it possible to call this on json body in postman?

Comment: @BloodLoss In Postman, you need to copy/paste this in the body and specify the `Content-type: application/x-ndjson` HTTP header

Comment: error.

{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [index].",
                "line": 1,
                "col": 11
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [index].",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 11
    },
    "status": 400
}

Comment: I copy and paste above code and run on postman

Comment: @BloodLoss Do you use correct index names?

Comment: I've called it successfully just now. Try using `POST` instead.

Comment: this is my url , `..../data-dev/_search` and my index is data-dev

Comment: @BloodLoss You need to call this against `/_msearch` endpoint against your host, not `/_search`

Comment: this query is working. 
{"index": "index"}
{"sort": [{ "name.keyword" : "asc"}], "size": 3}
{"index": "name"}
{"sort": [{ "price.consumer" : "asc"}], "size": 3}

Comment: I changed to `_msearch`.